# Having issues with the .Visible property of a text box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a web application where a user can order a custom portrait drawings by making choices from a variety of radio button lists. There is an extra charge if they want multiple people in the portrait, so one of the questions is whether or not there will be an additional person. They can select either "Yes" or "No" from a radio button list (the choices are currently in that order, with Yes at index 0 and No at index 1). If the user selects No, nothing happens and they move on to the next question. But if they click yes, a text box whose Visible property is currently set to False appears and they enter the number of additional people.

The problem is that I can't get my text box to become visible. I currently have my `TextBox.Visible = True` line of code under the radio button list's `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Here's the whole subroutine:

```
    Protected Sub RadioButtonListAdditional_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButtonListAdditional.SelectedIndexChanged
            Dim characters As Integer
            If RadioButtonListAdditional.SelectedIndex = 0 Then  
                txtAdditionalChars.Visible = True
                characters = CInt(txtAdditionalChars.Text)
                additionalprice = characters * 5
            ElseIf RadioButtonListAdditional.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                additionalprice = 0
            End If
        End Sub
```

`additionalprice` was declared earlier. The rest of that just has to do with the pricing scale for the additional characters. Anyway, I feel like I'm really close to having it right and that I'm just missing something small - my VB is a little bit rusty. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you know if your raddioButton get the value of 0?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking...

Comment: What is the default value for `txtAdditionalChars.Visible` property you have used ? Under `SelectedIndex = 0` i can see it is set to `true`. If it is set to `false` in markup it won't render in browser.

Comment: Originally I had the Visible property set to `false` in the design view. Now that I've got it set to `true`, the textbox is showing up, but I only wanted it to show up when the user selected "Yes" from the radio button list, hence the reason it was within that If statement.

Comment: set `txtAdditionalChars.Visible = False` in `elseIf` part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `AutoPostBack = True` on your RadioButtonListAdditional object?

Or you may need to check whether you have code on Page_Load event that call

```
txtAdditionalChars.Visible = False
```

Please let me know if this helps

Comment: I don't have any `.Visible = false` code in the Page Load event. I'd forgotten to enable AutoPostBack so I just did that. For a second I thought it would work, but now I'm getting an error highlighting the `characters = Cint(txtAdditionalChars.Text)` line saying that `conversion from string "" to type integer is invalid` (but I think I'm getting that because there's nothing in the text box since it's still not showing up)

Comment: a question is txtAdditionalChars an empty textbox? you cannot convert empty string to type integer

Comment: it starts out empty, but if the user selects the "Yes" option from the radio button list, the text box is supposed to become visible and they enter a number, which is the string that gets converted to an integer. But since the text box won't show up, the application thinks it's empty and throws that error.

Comment: then you shouldn't put characters = CInt(txtAdditionalChars.Text) on that event, maybe on the button save click event or etc.

Answer (score 0):

In VB Net .. Radiobutton control ..

Do it in your Radiobutton CheckedChanged event .. something like this

```
if rb.Checked then txtbox.Visible = True
```